# Is there a NOT LIKE Function in infornatica?

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-data-integration-hub

I know Reg_match(, '.*ABC.*) is a Like operator in INFA

how can I get a NOT LIKE FUNCTION?
EXAMPLE:
Where Not LIKE %DAVID% and NOT LIKE %ADAM%

Answer (score 2):

If you are using informatica 10 and up you can use `SQL_LIKE`.

```
SQL_LIKE(subject, pattern, escape character)
```

For lower versions or if you want to use something that will work for your scenario, then you can use 'INSTR()' to check and act accordingly. it may not work for pattern matching like _ but it will work for normal like scenario.

```
IIF ( INSTR(col,'DAVID') = 0 AND INSTR(col,'ADAM') = 0, do_blah, do_nah)
```